# SQL Server 2005 - View with linked server vs Query with linked server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

- Server1 - Main reporting server
- Server2 - Other reporting server

I have a linked server setup between Server1 and Server2.

Server1 has a view that runs a query with multiple joins to gather data from Server2.

When I execute the view on Server1 for year to date data, it takes 5 minutes to run.

When I execute the query on Server1 outside of the view, the query takes 2 minutes.

I've also took the query and built a stored procedure, but that also ran in 5 minutes.

Why is there such a difference between running through a view and running just the query?

The beginning of the 'Query' plan is cut off but the same as the 'View' plan.

Execution Plan for Query
[image: Execution Plan for Query]

Execution Plan for View
[image: Execution Plan for View]

Comment: Have you tried putting the view on Server2 and querying that from Server1? Also, when asking about performance, query plans are usually very helpful.

Comment: I created the view on Server2 and ran it. 2 seconds.

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning this in the first comment, but the query would also be useful. Both the view and how you're calling the view. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You are either going to have to show us the actual View definition and the exact commands you are executing, or post the Query Plans and not just an image of them (which doesn't help us very much).